# AngularJS - two way binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, view, uislider, watch

I have the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/578jK/19/)

I want two way binding for these sliders that will eventually set the value in the service
Meaning that the on is changed also the second and the value in the service also

HTML:

```
<div>    
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
         <input type="range" ng-model="speakerVolume" />
         {{speakerVolume}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        <input type="range" ng-model="speakerVolume" />
        {{speakerVolume}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, voipService) {
  $scope.speakerVolume = voipService.speakerVolume;
  $scope.$watch("speakerVolume", function (newValue) {
      voipService.speakerVolume = newValue;
      voipService.setVolume(newValue);
  });
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, voipService) {
  $scope.speakerVolume = voipService.speakerVolume;
  $scope.$watch("speakerVolume", function (newValue) {
      $scope.speakerVolume = newValue;
      voipService.setVolume(newValue);
  });
});

myApp.service('voipService', function() {
    this.speakerVolume = 50;

    this.setVolume = function(newVal){
        self.speakerVolume = newVal;
    }
});
```

**Final Answer in Fiddle:**
[Fiddle - Final Answer](http://jsfiddle.net/578jK/22/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to watch also service value, not just scope variable

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, voipService) {
  $scope.speakerVolume = voipService.speakerVolume;
  $scope.$watch("speakerVolume", function (newValue) {
      voipService.speakerVolume = newValue;
  });
  $scope.$watch(function() {
      return voipService.speakerVolume;  
  }, function (newValue) {
      $scope.speakerVolume = newValue;
  });
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, voipService) {
  $scope.speakerVolume = voipService.speakerVolume;
  $scope.$watch("speakerVolume", function (newValue) {
      voipService.setVolume(newValue);
  });
  $scope.$watch(function(){
      return voipService.speakerVolume;
  }, function (newValue) {
      $scope.speakerVolume = newValue;
  });
});

myApp.service('voipService', function() {
    var self = this;
    this.speakerVolume = 50;

    this.setVolume = function(newVal){
        self.speakerVolume = newVal;
    }
});
```

second way is to use `$broadcast` in the service (when the value is changed) and update values in all controllers when this custom event is fired

Comment: Thanks. but it's not working for both ways. when slide with the second slider it does not move the first slider.

Comment: that's because you don't define a self variable in voipService, I overlooked it... try it now

Comment: You are right ! I've added the last edited answer in fiddle to the question. Thank you !